# Default sorting is not working

Tags: category

Please refer this following url http://www.trendycollections.in/kids-wear/boys-wear.html

All sorting is working Fine. But I have different issue. In the above url if i chose `Price lowest` under the `sort by` option then i will move to http://www.trendycollections.in/women-collections/sarees/designer-sarees.html, That category page also having `Price lowest` sorting.

If i chose `price highest`,Next category page also sorting by price highest

I think, i need to reset sort by option. I have set default sorting under `system->config->catalog->front end->Product Listing Sort by` as `Best value`. I can’t find where am i doing wrong here. if anybody know, please help me guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17718106/2047249). By default Magento remembers the sorting and limit parameters in session. So what you need to do is to tell it not to. 
This can be done easily by adding this line

```
<action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />
```

inside the toolbar block in your layout files.
So look in your layout files for all occurrences of

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
```

and add inside this tag the line mentioned above.
Clear the cache when your are done.

Comment: Now, all are working fine! but now i have one more issue. when i select latest arrival, it display from oldest product. that means FIFO order. If even i have change the direction on url, it doesn't work. I can't find where is mistake arise from? Plz help me na

Comment: I think this is the subject of an other question.

Comment: ok, i will make new thread. Thank you! But it works fine some times. If i try again one more time,it goes to back(the above issue occur again)

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/sorting-direction-doesnt-make-effect --This is the new thread for above issue. If you know, Kindly save me

Comment: It will cause other problems like changing the display mode (grid/list) and page size, that will be lost.