# Sorting direction doesn't make effect

Tags: category

Please refer this url http://www.trendycollections.in/women-collections/salwar-kameez-1/party-salwar-kameez.html?dir=desc&order=id

In the above url, sorting direction is descending order. if i change the sorting order manually to that url i.e)http://www.trendycollections.in/women-collections/salwar-kameez-1/party-salwar-kameez.html?dir=asc&order=id, It also display the same result with same order. i can't find how to resolve it. If anybody Know, Please save me guys

Answer (score 1):

To be able to sort by a certain attribute you will have to set `Available Product Listing Sort By` to 'yes' under `BE > Catalog > Manage Attributes` selecting the attribute you want to sort by. I don't think the `ID` or `entity_id` as it's called in the database is a default sorting attribute

[image]