# disableParamsMemorizing not working for toolbar on searchresults pages

Tags: magento-1.7, product-list

disableParamsMemorizing is working fine with the category pages. But when someone uses the toolbar within the searchresults pages the params are cached.

I have seen i need to put `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::disableParamsMemorizing` somewhere but i cannot find it. I have placed `<action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />` in my templates product toolbar. Why o why is this not working on search pages?

edit:
local.xml:

```
<!-- Quick search -->
<catalogsearch_result_index>
<reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>desc</param></action>
        <action method="setSortBy"><param>news_from_date</param></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>desc</param></action>
        <action method="setSortBy"><param>news_from_date</param></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <!-- Keep layered navigation always on top. Replace: after="currency" with: before="-" -->
        <!--<action method="unsetChild"><name>catalogsearch.leftnav</name></action>
        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>-->

        <!-- Remove currency switcher from sidebar -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
    </reference>

</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

i have nothing in my xml for the toolbar.

Comment: Provide some XML from your layout file. Also take a look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7364/146

Comment: edit done, i also read the post. I have put that code in my template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml and that is working great for category pages. The code also shows-up in/around the toolbar on the searchresult pages when i "inspect" the code, but it is still saving the sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this inside the `<catalogsearch_result_index>` tag

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
   <action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />
</reference>
```

Comment: You are king! Big thanks, this is working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Does disableParamsMemorizing still work on Magento 2?

Answer is: No, deprecated