# How to make category 'Default Product Listing Sort By' default option as 'Position'

Tags: category, ce-1.8.1.0, sorting

There is 'Default Product Listing Sort By' on every category

I setup ' Use Config Settings' for all categories and the config settings 'Product Listing Sort by' is 'Best Value'

I want to always products sort and show as 'Position'. but How can I make sort default option as 'Position?

[image]

[image]

Comment: John,Best value actually  the `position`(Position) field in magento is showing as
Best value.

Comment: @AmitBera Yeah I guess that too but I always find our sort option is 'Name' ..It seems someone change Sort option 'Name' and it's saved default or 'Name' become default. How can I force always 'Position' as default?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could either do it for each category or you could do it here as seen in the screenshot below

**UPDATE**
Otherwise try this

In the toolbar block there is a method called disableParamsMemorizing. This should disable the storing of parameters in session.
Try to add this in the toolbar block.

```
<action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />
```

or you can override the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List class and make the getToolbarBlock method look like this:

```
public function getToolbarBlock()
{
    if ($blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName()) {
        if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
            $block->disableParamsMemorizing();
            return $block;
        }
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, microtime());
    $block->disableParamsMemorizing();
    return $block;
}
```

[image: Check this one here]

Comment: As I upload picture, I already setup exactly same like your picture 'Best Value' Check Use Default but I still find my sort option is 'Name' on category

Comment: Take a look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705344/prevent-magento-from-caching-query-strings-such-as-limit-param/17718106#17718106
 and this one here

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7363/default-sorting-is-not-working

Comment: John if something worked for you then let us know

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'm checking the link and will let you know

Comment: @JohnG. If you're still around, don't forget to mark this question as accepted if it solved the problem for you!

Answer (score 1):

To change magento product list default sorting feature, you need to change 2 things

1) Select default selector from admin panel

```
Go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend
select from 'Product Listing Sort by'
```

By this way you will select default attribute for sorting

2)   To change default order, make change in following file

```
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php
```

Search

```
protected $_direction           = 'asc';
```

change to

```
protected $_direction           = 'desc';
```